# pyspark nested when throws exception

Tags: pyspark, azure-databricks

I have simple dataframe consisting of 3 most important columns: `ID`, `CAT` and `SUBCAT`.
I want to group results including only rows with some type of `SUBCAT`.
Everything works fine with below code:

```
subcategories = ["AA", "AB", "BA", "BB"]

df_grouped = df \
            .groupby("ID") \
            .agg(             
                 collect_set(when(col("SUBCAT").isin(subcategories), struct(*[df[columnName] for columnName in restOfColumns]))))
```

When I want to add "nested" `when` for differentiation list of allowed `SUBCATs` per `CAT`:

```
df_grouped = df \
            .groupby("ID") \
            .agg(             
                 collect_set(when(col("SUBCAT").isin( \
                                 when((col("CAT") == lit("A")), array([lit("AA"), lit("AB")])) \
                                 .otherwise(array([lit("BA"), lit("BB")])) \
                         ), struct(*[df[columnName] for columnName in restOfColumns]))))
```

, I start receiving exception:

```
cannot resolve '(df.SUBCAT IN (CASE WHEN (df.CAT = 'A') THEN array('AA', 'AB') ELSE array('BA', 'BB') END))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type but were: string != array<string>
```

I have read similar topics here and people got similar errors, but now with the same type of query. Is such "nested" `when` limitation of pyspark or my query is wrong?

Comment: Giving code that does not do what you want done isnt as useful. How about you gave a sample inpute and expected results..? There maybe a simpler way of doing what you want out there... who knows?

Comment: @wwnde I found out different way, just by having several conditions with `&` inside when.  I was just curious about this case.

Answer (score 1):

In the **first code** the string in the column is compared with the **strings in the list**.

But in the **second case** as `when` only supports returning literals and columns expressions according to this [documentation](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.2.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.Column.when.html), you are returning the **array of string literals** from the nested when.

`cannot resolve '(df.SUBCAT IN (CASE WHEN (df.CAT = 'A') THEN array('AA', 'AB') ELSE array('BA', 'BB') END))' due to data type mismatch: Arguments must be same type but were: string != array<string>`

That’s why it is giving the above exception of data type mismatch which arise **due to the comparison of the string in the column with the array of Strings**.

In this kind of cases, it is good to use other methods rather than nested when as **commented**.

Comment: Is there some way for doing some conversion so this is not compared to array of strings rather than to strings in the array?

Comment: I also tried to that by giving list of literals and converting it to normal list of strings but not succeeded. I'll update here if I got anything about this.